# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when recognizing audio

Tags: audio, classification, voice-recognition, librosa

I am writing a neural network for audio recognition

My code:

```
X_train = np.array((X_train), dtype=object)
Y_train = np.array((Y_train), dtype=object)

X_train_backup = X_train.copy()
Y_train_backup = Y_train.copy()

y_train_class = np.argmax(Y_train, axis=1)
print(y_train_class)

scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```

On the line `X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)`  returns an error: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

I can't figure out what's wrong(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnW7j.jpg)

I tried changing the np.array type, but it still gives an error

```
X_train = np.array((X_train), dtype=data_type)
Y_train = np.array((Y_train), dtype=data_type)
```